# Can we connect multiple pods to the same PVC?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volume-claims

I mean is there a one to one or many to one relationship between pod and PVC? Can I connect two or more pods to the same PVC(persistent volume claims) without deleting or disconnecting the earlier created pods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can I connect two or more pods to the same PVC(persistent volume claims) without deleting or disconnecting the earlier created pods?

Yes, this works. But in practice this is a bit more complicated.

Persistent Volumes can be created with different [access modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes). Your storage system may limit what *access modes* you can use. E.g. the access mode `ReadWriteMany` is only available in some storage systems. The access mode `ReadWriteOnce` is most commonly available.

For multiple Pods accessing a Persistent Volume mounted with access mode `ReadWriteOnce`, they must be scheduled to the **same node** to concurrently access the volume.

For multiple Pods accessing a Persistent Volume mounted with access mode `ReadWriteMany` or `ReadOnlyMany`, the Pods can be scheduled to different nodes. But in a "cloud provider" environment, where you use multiple Availability Zones in a Region, your Persistent Volume is typically only accessible within **one Availability Zone**, so you must make sure that your Pods are scheduled to the same Availability Zone. Cloud providers typically offer Regional volumes as well, but they are more expensive and you need to use a specific [storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) for this.

Comment: But, the accessModes setting is something you use on the PVC, right? As far as I understand, there can be multiple PVC(s) connected to a single PV, because of the accessModes field. But, I don't know if multiple pods can use the same PVC or not?

Comment: The accessMode on the PVC is what the app request, it will get a PV with at least support for that accessMode. Yes, there can be multiple Pods using the same PVC.

Comment: Does it say implicitly that the same PVC can not be shared with Pods?  "Resource quantities can be added and subtracted: for example, a node has a fixed quantity of each resource type that can be allocated to pods/containers; once such an allocation has been made, the allocated resources cannot be made available to other pods/containers without over-committing the resources. "
https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/main/scheduling/resources.md

Comment: @NEERAJSWARNKAR pods on the same node can share the same PVC.

Answer (score 8):

Yea, It's one of the common use case. If the PVC has a `accessMode` of `ReadWriteMany` then multiple pods can mount the volumes at the same time.

> Here the access modes are:

```
ReadWriteOnce -- the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
ReadOnlyMany -- the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes
ReadWriteMany -- the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes
```

for further details [access-modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)

Comment: But as far as I understand, the access mode is something that the PVC and PV share. That is, there can be multiple PVC(s) with respect to a PV. But, I don't if its the same with pods and PVC(s)

Comment: so roughly speaking, first part is the PVC and Storage Class, both of these resources help to create a persistent volume on storage system, now second part is if this volume has capability with access mode of RWM such as a NFS , it can be mounted by multiple Nodes then to Pods at the same time but if the Volume such a Block storage (iscsi voumes)  which has RWO,then it can only be mounted with single node.

Comment: these limitation comes from storage system such as file system and block storage, you can read further about it.