# Is it possible to create a Docker image that can be attached to a Kubernetes pod, and have access to its file system?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm investigating if it's possible for me to create a Docker image that can be attached to a Kubernetes pod and be able to access the pods' file system and modify its contents.

For example, the Docker image could have the vi tool installed whereas the pod would not have vi - is it possible for the image/container to attach to the pod to modify a log file with vi?

I am aware of [ephemeral containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/) but these don't seem to allow the functionality I am looking for?

Comment: A Pod doesn't have "a filesystem". A Pod has one or more containers, and each container has its own filesystem. You can share volumes between containers in a pod, but you can't share the root container filesystem.

Comment: @larsks so if I have `some_pod` which has `some_container` that has a file `/var/log/file.log`, there is no way to access this using an ephemeral container or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `some_pod` which has `some_container` and you want `/var/log/file.log` to be available in multiple containers in that pod, you can mount an ephemeral *volume* on `/var/log` and share that between containers, e.g:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container1
    image: someimage
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared_log
      mountPath: /var/log
  - name: container2
    image: someimage
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared_log
      mountPath: /var/log
  volumes:
  - name: shared_log
    emptyDir: {}
```

But this only works for containers that are created as part of the pod. There's no way to launch a container *after* the pod has been created and have it access the ephemeral volume.

You could use a stateful (i.e., not ephemeral) volume:

```
  volumes:
  - name: shared_log
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: shared_log
```

With a stateful volume configured, you create a new pod that exposes the same volume to your containers (with [some potential limitations depending on the nature of your persistent storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345577/can-we-connect-multiple-pods-to-the-same-pvc)).